# How can I get a "minimum" WordPress that only manages database things?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, disqus

My site is at [www.ethoma.com/wd/](http://www.ethoma.com/wd/).

As you can see, I already implemented the theme and all of the menus with my own code. I wanted to install WordPress on my site so I could simply type in my posts on WordPress and WordPress would then generate my home page and my view post pages. Then I could use Disqus for comments. Is there a WordPress I could get that wouldn't completely throw off what I have already done? Where?

I am a WordPress novice. I was wondering what level of post format customization, i.e. embedded ads, I could get with WordPress. Would I be better off just doing the dirty work myself? Finally, can I get Disqus comments without any blogging interface (with my own php setup)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress is designed to take over everything to do with page generation, so you'll not be able to install it in the way you describe.

The closest approach would be to convert your existing content into WP posts and pages, and your styling into a WP theme. But this isn't the kind of thing to recommend to a WP novice.

You'll save yourself a lot of work by jumping into WP with both feet. Start with a local (non-public) installation so you have a sandbox where screwups aren't visible. Find a theme that's good enough - don't look for something exactly like what you have. Once you're comfortable, replace your current website with a new WP installation, having first copied off all your content. Recreate your existing site using WP as an engine, and work from there.

Comment: If you STILL want to use your existing theme, I'd recommend using http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/thematic as a base and build your theme from there.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I think I will toughen up and write some php. I got disqus set up for the commenting, so that really was what I was after. Now users can log into Twitter,etc. to comment. Really, post formatting is a lot more flexible now when I do it.